# Angular + Jasmine Testing: Mock testing with arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, jasmine

I'm writing some Jasmine tests for my Campaigns service and I'd like to be able to create `mockRepo` array in my CampaignServices spec. The GET test is working, however, with CREATE, I'd like to add a new campaign to the array and unsure how I'd do that in my Jasmine test.

I've read over the Jasmine documentation, but can't see an elegant way where I could push a new array to the end by incrementing the ID count of a new campaign and then expecting that to match within the test.

Please find below the Campaigns model and service:
**Model: Campaigns.js**

```
var portal;
(function (portal) {
    var campaigns;
    (function (campaigns) {
        var Campaign = (function () {
            function Campaign(id, name, description, status, start, end, createdAt, updatedAt) {
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.description = description;
                this.status = status;
                this.start = start;
                this.end = end;
                this.createdAt = createdAt;
                this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
            }
            return Campaign;
        })();
        campaigns.Campaign = Campaign;
    })(campaigns = portal.campaigns || (portal.campaigns = {}));
})(portal || (portal = {}));
```

**Service: CampaignsService.js**

```
var portal;
(function (portal) {
    var campaigns;
    (function (campaigns) {
        'use strict';
        var CampaignsService = (function () {
            function CampaignsService(api) {
                this.mockRepo = [
                    new Campaign(1, 'Campaign 1', 'My new campaign', 'live', new Date(2015, 6, 2), new Date(2016, 3, 5), new Date(2015, 6, 2), new Date(2016, 3, 5)),
                    new Campaign(2, 'Campaign 2', 'My old campaign', 'complete', new Date(2014, 3, 3), new Date(2015, 3, 5), new Date(2015, 6, 2), new Date(2016, 3, 5))
                ];
                this.__resource = api.all('campaigns');
            }
            CampaignsService.prototype.getList = function () {
                return this.mockRepo;
                //return this.__resource.getList();
            };
            CampaignsService.prototype.get = function (id) {
                return this.mockRepo.filter(function (item) {
                    return item.id === id;
                })[0];               
            };
            CampaignsService.prototype.update = function (model) {
                var theCampaign = this.get(model.id);
                theCampaign.name = model.name;
                theCampaign.updatedAt = new Date();

            };
            CampaignsService.prototype.create = function (model) {
                model.id = this.mockRepo.length + 1;
                this.mockRepo.push(model);
                return model.id;
            };
            CampaignsService.prototype.delete = function (id) {
                this.mockRepo = this.mockRepo.filter(function (item) {
                    return item.id !== id;
                });
            };
            CampaignsService.$inject = ["Restangular"];
            return CampaignsService;
        })();
        campaigns.CampaignsService = CampaignsService;
        angular.module('olCampaigns').service('CampaignsService', CampaignsService);
    })(campaigns = portal.campaigns || (portal.campaigns = {}));
})(portal || (portal = {}));
```

Below is my spec with the GET passing, however, I haven't managed to CREATE a new campaign. Any suggestions on how best to implement that would be greatly appreciated.

**Spec: CampaignServices.js**

```
describe('Campaigns Service', function() {
    var campaigns = [];

    beforeEach(function() {
        campaigns = [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Campaign 1",
              "description": "My new campaign",
              "status": "live",
              "start": new Date(2015, 6, 2),
              "end": new Date(2016, 3, 5),
              "createdAt": new Date(2015, 6, 2),
              "updatedAt": new Date(2016, 3, 5)
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "Campaign 2",
              "description": "My old campaign",
              "status": "complete",
              "start": new Date(2014, 3, 3),
              "end": new Date(2015, 3, 5),
              "createdAt": new Date(2015, 6, 2),
              "updatedAt": new Date(2016, 3, 5)
            }
        ]
    });

    it('GET ALL campaigns', function() {
        expect(campaigns.length).toEqual(2);
        expect(campaigns[0]).toEqual({"id": "1","name": "Campaign 1","description": "My new campaign","status": "live","start": new Date(2015, 6, 2),"end": new Date(2016, 3, 5),"createdAt": new Date(2015, 6, 2),
        "updatedAt": new Date(2016, 3, 5)});
    });

    it('CREATE a campaign', function() {
        // Want to create a new campaign and add it to the campaigns array above
        newCampaign.id = this.campaignMocks.length + 1;
        this.campaigns.push(newCampaign);
        console.log(newCampaign.id)
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like you are stuck between implementation and how to set-up the test.  Your current passing test isn't actually testing any of your code.  You verified the hard code data is in fact the data.

Comment: True. Chris, any suggestions on how I could get myself unstuck out of this predicament?

Comment: A few suggestions.  If you make a plunkr, I can help get you set-up.  First, the notion of mocking data should be for tests only.  Therefore, the service itself should not have a mock repo.  Second, figure out where the data is coming from.  If some $http call, mock with $httpBackend to return the data and test your expectations of campaigns.  With respect to create test, figure out what you want to test.  Should be able to test array addition in array assuming you mocked the data as already indicated and probably should test the backend call to save to db if that is applicable.